# Regular expression in normal (standard) form

Tags: regular-expressions

Regular expressions can be reduced to a standard form. A **normal form** is either 0 or a term of the form 
$$ \sum_{i \in I} a_i + \sum_{j \in J} n^*_j + \sum_{k \in K} a_k \cdot n^*_k  + \sum_{l \in L} n^*_l \cdot n^{'}_l + \sum_{m \in M} E_m$$
where $E_m =1$ for all $m$, where $n_j, m_k, n_l,n_l'$ are normal forms different from 0 and 1 ,and we have $bounded(n^*_j)$ and  $bounded(n^*_l)$.

This definition is from [a 1999 paper by Corradini et al.](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ITA/ITA_1999__33_4-5/ITA_1999__33_4-5_447_0/ITA_1999__33_4-5_447_0.pdf) where completeness is proved.

Is it possible to have some references or examples about it?

Comment: What does "eight 0" mean?  Is that a typo?  What does "$E_m=1$ for $m$" mean?  What's meant by $bounded(\cdot)$?  Please make the post self-contained, and proof-read it.  What do you mean by "This assertion is definited"?  Can you provide a reference/citation for that link that will be useful even if the link stops working?  For instance, provide, title, authors, and where published.  Then, what is your specific question?  "Is it possible to have some reference or examples" is not specific enough.  What exactly do you want to know?  Please edit the question to clarify these points.

Comment: @Michela: I edited your question because some spelling errors made it hard to understand.

Comment: I agree with D.W.; even form aside, it is not clear what your question is. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: You still haven't defined $bounded(\cdot)$ nor clarified what exactly what you want to know.  Please provide a full citation for that paper (title, authors, and where published), so we can identify the paper even if the link stops working.   Also, if $E_m=1$ for all $m$, why do you even have the variable $E_m$?  Why don't you replace $\sum_{m \in M} E_m$ with $\sum_{m \in M} 1$ or just $1$?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. What research have you done? If you want other references/papers, have you used Google Scholar to find other papers that cite the Corradini paper and looked at them?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for examples.

I would suggest checking whether some very simple expressions like $a^*$, $abc$, ... are in normal form or not. This helps getting familiar with the definition. For example, what do $0$ and $1$ mean, and what is "bounded"?

Then you can move to more complex expressions like $a.b^*$ and $(a^*b)^*$, ... When one of these is not in normal form, you can try to give an equivalent expression in normal form. Note that it should be possible to put any expression in normal form using the rules given in the Corradini et al. paper. When reading their completeness proof it is good to have a few examples at hand on which you can check the steps of the transformation method.

You're also looking for references.

You can use [Google Scholar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Scholar) to find papers that cite the Corradini paper. You can also search for papers concerned with the nondeterminism in regular expressions since this is one of the motivation of the normal form you're interested in.

Hope this helps.